# How to change the word "Proof" in the proof environment?

Tags: theorems, amsthm, naming

I want to change the word "Proof" into "Solution". Of course the following works.

```
\begin{proof}[Solution] \end{proof}
```

But it's quite cumbersome to add this additional [Solution] every time. Is there a way to make it automatic?

Edit: I'm using `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Solution]
This is a solution.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi John, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you provide a bit more detail, such as which package you're using to give the `proof` environment (presumably it's `amsthm`, but who knows?). Ideally, please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to redefine `\proofname`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is a solution.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One should note that `\proofname` is controlled by `babel` if the package is loaded, so something like `\addto\languageXYZ{\renewcommand\proofname{ABC}}` is needed in this case.

Comment: I was just going to ask that. lol

Comment: one should also note that `amsbook` incorporates (rather than loads -- there are subtle differences) `amsthm`, so it's not necessary to `\usepackage{amsthm}`.

Comment: For those writing French, the corresponding command is `\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\proofname{Preuve}}`.

Comment: This answer is not suitable if we also want to use the original `proof` environment in the document. I thought this would work reasonably well `\newenvironment{solution}
{\begin{proof}[Solution]}
{\end{proof}}` but the "Solution" word sometimes doesn't appear in the beginning of the environment.