# How to remove the word "Proof:" from the environment proof?

Tags: theorems, ieeetran, naming

I am writing a paper and I will prove a theorem in an appendix because the proof is lengthy. When I use the following code,

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{}

\begin{document}

\appendices
\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{theorem1}}

\begin{proof}
We will use induction to prove this theorem.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

I would like to remove the word "Proof:" from the proof as this is already explained in the name of the appendix.

I have checked the question [How to change the word “Proof” in the proof environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62020/how-to-change-the-word-proof-in-the-proof-environment). I tried to change the name to be blank using

```
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{}
```

However this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this code

```
\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]

\end{proof}
```

A full example:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}

\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{theorem1}
Toasters can fly.
\end{thm}

\appendices
\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{theorem1}}

\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]
We will use induction to prove this theorem.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work, it removed the word but not the colon. I am left with

 : We will use induction ....

Comment: Add also `\unskip` before `\nopunct`.

Comment: @BHamza Remove the `\renewcommand{\proofname}{}` line.

Comment: @egreg Removed the line, and used the \nopunct it indented the first line to the left, but the colon still exist. Thank you.

Comment: @BHamza If you type `\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]` you should be on your way.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a MWE in order to show that your suggestion works. Welcome to TeX.SX! Good answer!

Comment: I am sorry, I thought it is working, but the colon is still there. I do not understand why it does not produce the same output as yours.

Comment: You are using TexLive or online editors? I tested it over [link](https://www.writelatex.com/) and [link](https://www.sharelatex.com/) and it works.

Comment: @egreg -- this is, of course, the "logical" answer, but with tex live 2012 it does *not* work; it leaves the colon, as reported.  and, though it probably doesn't matter, the qed box is a black, not open, square.  so it's advisable to make sure that the class and all packages are the most recent ones.  (didn't test that.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tested it also with TL2012 and it works.

Comment: I am using WinEdt. The colon is still there. What should I do?

Comment: @egreg -- i've taken this off-line.  expect email.

Comment: @egreg, Can you help because the question has not yet been answered. How can I remove the colon?!

Comment: @BHamza As you can see, I get *no* colon, so I can't tell you how to remove it.

Comment: @BHamza You are probably running an old TeX distribution; I get the colon if I use TeX Live 2011 (or older) together with a warning `ATTENTION: \proof is deprecated (line 17). Use \IEEEproof instead`. Can you confirm?

Comment: @BHamza I've added an answer for solving your problem; but you should upgrade your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Karo's answer, which is perfect for `IEEEtran.cls` version 1.8 released on 2012-12-27 (which is included in up-to-date TeX Live 2012 distributions and in TeX Live 2013 and later), I'll add a workaround for previous versions of the class:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}

\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

%% define a \killproofname command that works with both
%% IEEEtran.cls version 1.7a or version 1.8
\makeatletter
\@ifclasslater{IEEEtran}{2012/12/26}
 {\newcommand{\killproofname}{\unskip\nopunct}}
 {\newcommand{\killproofname}[1]{\unskip\aftergroup\ignorespaces\ignorespaces}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{theorem1}
Toasters can fly.
\end{thm}

\appendices
\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{theorem1}}

\begin{proof}[\killproofname]
We will use induction to prove this theorem.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result compiling with TeX Live 2011, which has `IEEEtran.cls` version 1.7a, released on 2007/03/05:

[image]