# Avoid extra linebreak at the end of modified "proof" environment

Tags: environments, amsthm

This question is related to [How to change the word "Proof" in the proof environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62020/how-to-change-the-word-proof-in-the-proof-environment).
I would like that the proofs in my document begin with "*Proof.* ---", instead of the standard "Proof." by default. But if I try to modify this setting, whatever solution I tried, I also get an extra line break at the end of the proof (and the \qed is placed on the extra blank line).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\noindent \itshape Proof. ---}}{\qed}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
  My theorem.
\end{theo}

\begin{proof} In two steps:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item The first step
  \item The second step
  \qedhere
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in this MWE, the "*Proof. ---*" is correctly set, but I get an extra new line. I tried some solutions (found on SE) to remove the extra new line, but it seems that none of them is compatible with the "renaming" of proof environment. How can I do both?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a reason why the proof env is defined the way it is. Copy the definition from `amsthm.sty` to your preamble and modify that. This very naïvely approach in the MWE is asking for trouble.

Comment: Well, that's a bit heavy for such a little issue... I kept trying other solutions and found a satisfactory one, posted below as an answer, just in case.

Comment: In any case you need to look at the original definition to figure out what to change (as you did below)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2):

A solution: using the `xpatch` package to modify only the `\@addpunct` instruction. This is working:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\proof{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{.} ---}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
  My theorem.
\end{theo}

\begin{proof} In two steps:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item The first step
  \item The second step
  \qedhere
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do the job. Actually, it should be `\@addpunct{.} ---`

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference, or which problems could arise with `\@addpunct{. ---}`?

Comment: Try with `\begin{proof}[Démonstration?]` with both codes.