# Rename amsthm proof environment but retain dot

Tags: amsthm

I am following the directions from [this SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62020/how-to-change-the-word-proof-in-the-proof-environment) to change the text in an amsthm "Proof" to 증명, which is the Korean word for the same.

If I put in Latin text, it works just fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{kotex}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{My proof} 

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
To get a contradiction, suppose that $3 = 4$. 
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

prints `My proof.  To get ...` However, changing the third line to

```
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{증명}
```

prints `증명  To get a contradiction, suppose that 3=4.` with the dot missing. On the other hand,

```
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{증명.}
```

prints `증명..   To get a contradiction, suppose that 3=4.` with two dots!

How do I get just one dot?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue with `pdflatex`, but not with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

The reason is that the space factor after Korean characters is set to 1001: it is used for deciding whether breaking before Hangul at transitions, I believe.

However, this conflicts with `\@addpunct` that adds its argument only if the current space factor is 1000 or less.

Solution: add `\@`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{kotex}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{증명\@} 

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
To get a contradiction, suppose that $3 = 4$. 
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]