# How to create a proof environment with a different typeset name in addition to the original proof environment?

Tags: polyglossia, amsthm

Picking up on [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62020/how-to-change-the-word-proof-in-the-proof-environment#comment1217237_62021), how can I define a proof environment with a different typeset name than "Proof" (say, "Explanation") in such a way that the new environment coexists rather than supplants the original proof environment?

I currently use the `amsthm` package to generate `proof` environments, but if it helps, I don't mind loading another package.

Comment: Give `\renewcommand\proofname{Explanation}` a try.

Comment: @Mico Isn't this essentially the same solution as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62021/21685)?

Comment: Ah, I had missed the fact that you want a solution that coexists with the existing `proof` environment. Let me post a longer answer.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. If you don't mind, could you please also indicate in your answer how it can be done in a bilingual document that uses the `polyglossia` package?

Comment: Which are the two languages?

Comment: @Mico Does it matter? Won't the same principle apply to all languages? But if the specific second language is critical, then Hebrew; the first one being English.

Comment: Thanks. It matters for how polyglossia's machinery needs to be told to swing into action.

Comment: @Mico Would you rather I open another question for the `polyglossia` variation?

Comment: Yes please. I've been struggling for the past half hour with augmenting my answer to handle multiple languages, using either `babel` or `polyglossia`, but so far without luck. I've generalized the answer to use a macro called `\explanationname` instead of hard-coding the name of the environment. Maybe that'll be useful in making language-specific adaptations.

Comment: @Mico [Voilà](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664973/21685).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a new LaTeX environment called, say, `explanation`. Entering a LaTeX environment automatically starts a new TeX group. This environment first redefines the macro `\proofname` and then opens a `proof` environment. At the end of the `explanation` environment, the `proof` environment is closed. This approach "works" because the scope of the  redefinition of the `\proofname` is confined to the current TeX group and is therefore "forgotten" when the `explanation` environment ends.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand\explanationname{Explanation} % could be made language-dependent
\newenvironment{explanation}%
   {\renewcommand\proofname\explanationname%
    \begin{proof}}%
   {\end{proof}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{explanation} bla bla bla \end{explanation}
\begin{proof} ble ble ble \end{proof}
\begin{explanation} bli bli bli \end{explanation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've added a comment to your code saying "could be made language-dependent". How could it be made language dependent?

Comment: @EvanAad - Indeed, a slightly cryptic remark. Sorry. I was thinking about how `babel` "knows" how to modify a slew of macros from their (generally) English-language defaults to equivalent values according to whichever language (other than English) is in the foreground. E.g., if `babel` is loaded and `nswissgerman` (hey, I'm based in Zurich!) is in effect, executing `\proofname` generates "Beweis" rather than "Proof". What I couldn't figure out was how to create a test of the form `\newcommand\explanationname{\ifenglish Explanation\else\ifnswissgerman Erklärung\fi\fi}`. [continued]

Comment: @EvanAad -   Unfortunately, conditionals such as `\ifenglish` and `\ifnswissgerman` don't seem to exist. If you happen to know how to test for which language is active or "in the foreground", I think you should be almost done. My knowledge of `babel` and `polyglossia` simply isn't up to the task, I'm afraid.

Comment: @EvanAad - I just noticed that user extraordinaire `egreg` figured out how to employ the command `\appto{\captionshebrew}{...}` to get the job done. If anyone could figure it out, egreg for sure would be on that list...