# How to create a proof environment with a different typeset name in addition to the original proof environment, in a non-English language?

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew, right-to-left, proof-package

This post is a direct extension of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664971/21685). How can I define a proof environment with a different typeset name than "Proof" in a non-English document *in addition to* the original proof environment, rather than in lieu of it?

The language I am interested in is Hebrew, and the LaTeX language support I use is provided by the `polyglossia` package in tandem with the `xelatex` engine, but I'm also interested in the combination `babel` + `lualatex`.

Following is a LaTeX document, saved as `~/test.tex`, as a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{משפט}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

Following is an interesting theorem.
\begin{theorem}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

When the following instructions are executed in the Terminal:

> > cd ~
> > xelatex test

the file `~/test.pdf` is created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows.

[image: A basic framework for a mathematical paper in Hebrew.]

Note that Hebrew is a right-to-left language.

The desired solution would enable me to add the following to `~\test.tex` immediately below the `\end{proof}` line:

```
\begin{explanation}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}
```

with the resulting PDF file displaying like this:

[image: Desired output]

Note that the desired output can be accomplished on an ad-hoc basis by adding the option `[הסבר]` to the `proof` environment, thus: `\begin{proof}[הסבר] ... \end{proof}`. However, I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to declare a new environment with a different name than `proof`.

Comment: Just the name or also the direction? I’m not sure what’s the desired output.

Comment: The desired output is that if you add under the `\end{proof}` a copy of the `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}` part, but change the two occurrences of the word `proof` into `explanation`, the new PDF document would look similar to the one shown above with the difference that under the proof there'll be another proof that would look almost the same as the one above it, except that the first (i.e. right-most) word won't be "הוכחה" but rather "הסבר".

Comment: @JavierBezos I have expanded my post by elaborating on, and exemplifying, the desired solution.

Comment: @EvanAad I added a perhaps simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add to `\captions<language>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}
\newenvironment{explanation}
  {\let\proofname\explanationname\begin{proof}}%
  {\end{proof}}

\newcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}% default
\newcommand{\explanationname}{Explanation}% default
\appto{\captionshebrew}{%
  \renewcommand\theoremname{משפט}%
  \renewcommand\explanationname{הסבר}%
}
\appto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand\theoremname{Theorem}%
  \renewcommand\explanationname{Explanation}%
}

\begin{document}

Following is an interesting theorem.

\begin{theorem}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{theorem}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different approach, perhaps simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\newcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}% default
\newcommand{\explanationname}{Explanation}% default
\appto{\captionshebrew}{%
  \renewcommand\theoremname{משפט}%
  \renewcommand\explanationname{הסבר}%
}
\appto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand\theoremname{Theorem}%
  \renewcommand\explanationname{Explanation}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{explanation}{o}
 {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\proof[\explanationname]}{\proof[#1]}}
 {\endproof}

\begin{document}

Following is an interesting theorem.

\begin{theorem}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}
\begin{explanation}[הסבר נוסף]
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{theorem}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}
\begin{explanation}[Further explanation]
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

And for `babel` with either `luatex` or  (with a minimal change) `xetex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\theoremname}

\newenvironment{explanation}%
   {\renewcommand\proofname{\explanationname}%
    \begin{proof}}
   {\end{proof}}

% For LuaTeX. For XeTeX use bidi=bidi
\usepackage[bidi=basic, english, hebrew, provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}

\setlocalecaption{hebrew}{theorem}{משפט}
\setlocalecaption{hebrew}{explanation}{הסבר}
\setlocalecaption{english}{theorem}{Theorem}
\setlocalecaption{english}{explanation}{Explanation}

\begin{document}

Following is an interesting theorem.
\begin{theorem}
  A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
  But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
  A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
  But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\selectlanguage{english}

Following is an interesting theorem.
\begin{theorem}
  A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
  But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
  A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
  But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is based on [Mico's answer to my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664972/21685). However, this solution falls short for a *bilingual* document in which one wants the `explanation` environment to be language-sensitive the way the `proof` environment is language-sensitive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{משפט}

% The following is based on Mico's answer here:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664972/21685
% BEGIN
\newcommand\explanationname{Explanation} % could be made language-dependent
\newenvironment{explanation}%
   {\begingroup
    \renewcommand\proofname\explanationname%
    \begin{proof}[הסבר]}%
   {\end{proof}%
    \endgroup}
% END

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

Following is an interesting theorem.

\begin{theorem}
A house is not a home.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
   A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there.
   But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home.
\end{proof}
\begin{explanation}
   When there's no one there to hold you tight,
   and no one there you can kiss goodnight,
   a house is not a home.
\end{explanation}

\end{document}
```